# How to recover files in git repository

Tags: macos, git, recover

I had a project connected to a local git repository. I decided to reinit that after some mess with branches and commits. Firstly, I deleted old repository with "rm -r .git", and than created new one with "git init". After that, I found out my work directory looking the same way as if my project was only created - the results of all my work are gone.

Trying many recipes from the internet didn't give results. Please, give me a cue, is there any chance to recover my project's files or not.

Comment: So, you deleted all your files including your actual files, not just the git files? Well... do you have a backup?

Comment: what was your last checkout when you did the rm -rf on the .git directory?  If it wasn't the 'tip' of the master branch, then yes: you nuked some of your work.

Answer (score 0):

In the case your  "local repository" means you did `git clone /path/to/your/local/repo`, yes you can restore it by cloning again with  `git ckibe /path/to/your/local/repo`, or `git remote add origin /path/to/your/local/repo && git fetch && git pull origin/master` ).

Same thing if you cloned from a remote repository.

Otherwise, there is no way to recover your files with git, except if you removed by a graphical interface (which move to a trash folder instead of making a real deletion) or if you have a back up.